# Reusing model fitted by cross_val_score in sklearn using joblib

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I created the following function in python:

```
def cross_validate(algorithms, data, labels, cv=4, n_jobs=-1):
    print "Cross validation using: "
    for alg, predictors in algorithms:
        print alg
        print
        # Compute the accuracy score for all the cross validation folds. 
        scores = cross_val_score(alg, data, labels, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs)
        # Take the mean of the scores (because we have one for each fold)
        print scores
        print("Cross validation mean score = " + str(scores.mean()))

        name = re.split('\(', str(alg))
        filename = str('%0.5f' %scores.mean()) + "_" + name[0] + ".pkl"
        # We might use this another time 
        joblib.dump(alg, filename, compress=1, cache_size=1e9)  
        filenameL.append(filename)
        try:
            move(filename, "pkl")
        except:
            os.remove(filename) 

        print 
    return
```

I thought that in order to do cross validation, sklearn had to fit your function.

However, when I try to use it later (f is the pkl file I saved above in `joblib.dump(alg, filename, compress=1, cache_size=1e9))`:

```
alg = joblib.load(f)  
predictions = alg.predict_proba(train_data[predictors]).astype(float)
```

I get no error in the first line (so it looks like the load is working), but then it tells me `NotFittedError: Estimator not fitted, call`fit`before exploiting the model.` on the following line.

What am I doing wrong? Can't I reuse the model fitted to calculate the cross-validation? I looked at [Keep the fitted parameters when using a cross_val_score in scikits learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483893/keep-the-fitted-parameters-when-using-a-cross-val-score-in-scikits-learn) but either I don't understand the answer, or it is not what I am looking for. What I want is to save the whole model with joblib so that I can the use it later without re-fitting.

Comment: The method `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate` has a `return_estimator` flag you can use to retrieve the fitted models.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The real reason your model is not fitted is that the function `cross_val_score` first copies your model before fitting the copy : [Source link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L197)

So your original model has not been fitted.

Answer (score 14):

It's not quite correct that cross-validation has to fit your model; rather a k-fold cross validation fits your model k times on partial data sets. If you want the model itself, you actually need to fit the model again on the whole dataset; this actually isn't part of the cross-validation process. So it actually wouldn't be redundant to call

```
alg.fit(data, labels)
```

to fit your model after your cross validation.

Another approcach would be rather than using the specialized function `cross_val_score`, you could think of this as a special case of a cross-validated grid search (with a single point in the parameter space). In this case `GridSearchCV` will by default refit the model over the entire dataset (it has a parameter `refit=True`), and also has `predict` and `predict_proba` methods in its API.

Comment: that is just not true. Of course cross-validation has to fit your model, whether it is on partial data sets or on the whole, doesn't make a difference regarding the 'fitted' character of the model

Answer (score 0):

Cross_val_score does not keep the fitted model
Cross_val_predict does
There is no cross_val_predict_proba but you can do this

[predict_proba for a cross-validated model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787500/predict-proba-for-a-cross-validated-model)